# Asynchronous programming in JS

Tags: javascript

I often hear something like "working knowledge of asynchronous programming" regards JavaScript in job descriptions etc, but I'm not sure what it mean - is it about callbacks and promises or is there something else to it? I'd appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, effectively. More generally, it's about understanding the asynchronous nature of the most common JavaScript environments (web browsers, Node.js) and being fully versed in using callbacks, promises, `async`/`await` (in modern environments), etc. Understanding the [closures-in-loops problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), why you can't [*return* the result from an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), that code that looks like it's below other code in a function [may run earlier than the code apparently above it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) (because the code above it is in a callback), etc.

Comment: I'd mention (DOM) event processing in general.

Comment: @Bergi - It's just a special case of the general pattern. I don't want to turn the answer into an encyclopedia of asynchronous situations, just calling out the biggies.